# Windows update KB4530734 fails with error 0x800F0816 and triggers a system restore on reboot

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

On Windows 7 x64 Windows update KB4530734 (December 10, 2019—KB4530734 (Monthly Rollup)) fails with error 0x800F0816 and triggers a system restore on reboot. When installing the update, it finishes with a hint to reboot. After the reboot, the failure and the error code can be seen in the Windows Update history.

I already tried the following things to no avail:

- [Windows Update Troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027322/windows-update-troubleshooter)

  - this reports inconsistent results when rerunning
  - this reports inconsistent result in overview vs detailed view
- `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth`

  - on the first run it said it found and fixed some problems
- `sfc /scannow`

  - on the first run it said it found and fixed some problems
- Resetting the Windows Update Components with [Reset-Windows-Update-Tool](https://github.com/ManuelGil/Reset-Windows-Update-Tool)
- installing all available outstanding Windows Updates

How do I fix this without reinstalling Windows?

Comment: Why bother to fix it? Windows 7 is (or soon wiil be, depending on contract) out of support, so switch to another OS or turn off updates.\

Comment: See if anything here helps>>>>>>https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-error-0x800f0816/